# NFS server dropped connection momentarily, now df, ls, and umount all hang

Tags: arch-linux, mount, nfs, fstab

I have this fstab entry:

```
machine.local:/srv/files /res/files nfs defaults 0 0
```

It was working great until machine.local dropped the connection momentarily. Now, the share isn't accessible. `df`, `umount /res/files`, `ls /res` all hang forever.

What should I do, short of a reboot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NFS really ought to reconnect once the NFS server is back up. It may take a few minutes (it needs to notice the timeout). The `timeo` option lets you change how long the timeout takes.

`umount -f /res/files` will probably unmount the share (and kill all the processes waiting on it), if you try it a few times.

On older kernels, if you have the share mounted with `intr`, you can kill the waiting processes. On newer kernels (2.6.25+), you can `kill -9` them.

NFS client options are documented in the `nfs(5)` manpage.

Note: Some versions of `umount` have a [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642331) where they try to stat the filesystem before unmounting it. If so, you'll need a trivial C program like this:

```
#include <sys/mount.h>
int main() {
    const char p[] = "/res/files";
    umount2(p, MNT_FORCE);
    umount2(p, MNT_FORCE);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do a lazy umount:

```
umount -l /res/files
mount /res/files
```

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=17567

Comment: That actually leaves it mounted, and leaves your hung programs hung. Of course, it'll finally finish unmounting once it reconnects to the NFS server...

Comment: I should add that I immediately mount the share again. In fact, I will add that.

Comment: A lazy unmount just removes it from the mountpount, it's still actually mounted. Just not visible anymore. So, when you remount it, you have it mounted twice at that point. That's likely not really a problem, just something to be aware of.

Comment: How can I detect that second mount? `df` shows one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a system that supports it, you could try force-unmounting the filesystem and then re-mounting:

```
umount -f /res/files
mount /res/files
```

Comment: I get `umount.nfs4: /res/files: device is busy`, and `df` is still hanging.